# JdbcTemplate dynamic table name and SQL injection

Tags: sql, database, spring, sql-injection, jdbctemplate

I have a concern about SQL injection with spring's JdbcTemplate in some code similar to this :

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, new TableMapper());
```

The "tableName" variable is added by concatenation because it is not possible to pass it as a parameter with JdbcTemplate.

The "tableName" variable can only be edited by administrators but I would like to know if it is technically possible to do an SQL injection attack on this query.

Otherwise can you describe a safe way to do this?

Comment: Are you performing any kind of sanitisation on `tableName`?

Comment: No, I don't know how I could sanitize efficiently as I don't know the table name. Any idea about this ?

Comment: It should not be edited but selectable from a list of existing tables/views. List of available tables obtaining is DB specific. Add appropriate DB tag to your question

Comment: The code is meant to be used as a library and I have no control on future interfaces, But I indeed might check that the table exists before doing any query. Thx

Comment: @xte In that case you could inform users of the library that they're responsible for sanitising table names etc..?

Comment: Yes That's the plan for now indeed. The point is that I'm not sure it is even needed. Is it really possible to insert SQL code there ? Is there really no alternative to concatenation for table names in JdbcTemplate ?

Answer (score 1):

```
  String prepQuery = "INSERT INTO $tabname ( name, dataid, groupid, uniqueid, type, filecontainer, filetype, fileurl, filepath, uploadstatus) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   Object[] params = new Object[] {
          name,
          dataid,
          groupid,
          uniqueid,
          type,
          container,
          filetype,
          file_url,
          path,
          filePresent
  };
  prepQuery = prepQuery.replace("$tableName",dataid);
  int i = jdbcTemplate.update(prepQuery ,params);
```

This is just an alternate but table name cannot be passed in a dynamic way.

reference [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jdbc.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved answer that uses Java 17+

```java
 String prepQuery = "INSERT INTO %s( name, dataid, groupid, uniqueid, type, filecontainer, filetype, fileurl, filepath, uploadstatus) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
   Object[] params = new Object[] {
          name,
          dataid,
          groupid,
          uniqueid,
          type,
          container,
          filetype,
          file_url,
          path,
          filePresent
  };
  int i = jdbcTemplate.update(prepQuery.formatted(dataid) ,params);
```

Note: Changed the query to use `%s`. This uses an instance version of `String::format`, called `formatted`

Answer (score -7):

Yes, it is possible. I'd suggest to modify your code like this:

```
jdbcTemplate.query("SELECT * FROM ?", new Object[]{tableName},new TableMapper());
```

This safely inserts tableName into your query ;)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to pass the table name as a parameter in jdbc - jdbcTemplate. Other parameters are passed as arguments but the table name can't be passed that way.